# Exploding Ring particle effect with Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, effect, particles

I found the Exploding Ring particle effect best suite what I need but I could not figure out how to control the blast radius of this particle effect. I.e: not exploding out the whole screen but only exploding in a small circle

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest method is to use Particle Designer (http://particledesigner.71squared.com/).  It has full Cocos2D support and you can visually see what you want with the editor without having to code it.  You can see how to integrate the export files at [http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:particles?s[]=particle](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aparticles?s%5B%5D=particle).  Hope that helps!